# What is the bare minimum I should install on a headless Red Hat (or CentOS), or Ubuntu, box to be able run GUI programs through X11 via SSH

Tags: linux, x11, gui

I access my machine via `ssh` with the `-Y` parameter. I have a local X server installed (XQuartz for Mac)

The remote server is a barebones command line only box.

What is the bare minimum I would need to install on the remote linux box to be able to run a GUI application?

As an example of the GUI apps I want to run, I would like to run Oracle SQLDeveloper and Eclipse. Potentially Firefox too.

I don't need a desktop, or window manager, or any associated tools, if I can help it.

Comment: Doesn't `ssh -Y` just work? What kind of error you get?

Comment: Sorry. Should have clarified. XQuartz and `ssh -Y` work fine. However, the remote linux box I am logging in to does not have any GUI packages installed. I would like know what is the least I need to install on it

Comment: @Vihung are you saying then that you want to run these GUI programs on the remote server itself? I imaging the minimum you need is the `base` and `sshd` packages (`base` is always required, `sshd` gives you `ssh`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use-case you only need to install `xauth` (and its dependencies) on the distant machine, and the applications you want to run along with their dependencies. For example, for Eclipse you should only need a non-headless JDK and Eclipse itself.

You don't need a desktop environment or even a window manager, you'll end up using their equivalents on your local system (the machine running the X server).

Answer (score 2):

The minimal I've been able to get away with is the `xauth` package and any of its dependencies. At that point, once the programs you want to run are installed with their dependencies, they should display to your local machine correctly.